# Draggable image Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

Im super new and have slowly been working on an app. ive kinda hit a road block when ive tried to make an image moveable by pressing it and dragging it. I used this as my inital reference.

http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/03/simple-moving-object-with-touch-events.html

But when I do that and run it nothing happens when i press the image to move it around. Heres what my Code looks like.  I feel like it is a super simple solution. I dont have any errors in the code according to android studio.

Below is my activity_touch.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_touch"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#24d7d4"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.daniel.movebutton.activity_touch">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/bunny"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the activity_touch.java

```
package com.example.daniel.movebutton;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class activity_touch extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_touch);
}
}
```

Then this is my TouchActivity.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TouchActivity extends Activity {

private ViewGroup mainLayout;
private ImageView image;

private int xDelta;
private int yDelta;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_touch);
    mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_touch);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    image.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener());
}

private OnTouchListener onTouchListener() {
    return new OnTouchListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
            final int y = (int) event.getRawY();

            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams =                  (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
          view.getLayoutParams();

                    xDelta = x - lParams.leftMargin;
                    yDelta = y - lParams.topMargin;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Toast.makeText(TouchActivity.this,
                            "thanks for new location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =     (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = x - xDelta;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = y - yDelta;
                    layoutParams.rightMargin = 0;
                    layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
                    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;
            }
            mainLayout.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    };
}
}
```

I really feel like Im just missing something in the activity_touch.java

Any help would be great! Thanks guys!

Comment: have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: When i go to Run > Debug > App after it starts running I dont get any errors in the console at the bottom

Comment: use break point to check values.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Im super new.

Comment: If you are super new, I suggest getting a basic underdstanding how to code first. This request is an advance goal to achieve for someone starting out. Rome wasn't built in a day. We all want to smash out the next killer app but without the basic understading you will struggle

Comment: Solid advice but in my defense I've learned more in the time I've been working on the app than the 2 Java class I took in college.